# Exp:resso Store and PayPal Express

Tags: expresso-store, paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-express-checkout

I'm thinking of using Exp:resso Store for my client's site, and I'm thinking of using PayPal Express Checkout as the payment gateway. Can anyone please shed some light on how these two work together?

Where do I enter my API Signature so Store can connect to PayPal?

What details do I have to send to PayPal?

Do users have to log in to a PayPal account before they can confirm their purchase?

Thanks in advance, sorry for being clueless!

Comment: Have you looked over the documentation for Exp:resso store? That should have something about how to integrate it with some of the various payment processors. As for the specific questions about Paypal and confirming their purchase, I think the answer is "no", but check with Paypal itself to confirm that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal Express is fully supported by Store. Once you have Store installed you'll see it in the main menu in the EE control panel.

Go to Store > Settings > Payment methods and then "Add Payment Method". From the "Payment Plugin" dropdown select "Paypal Express". You'll then be asked for your username, password, and signature, etc.

[image: see screenshot]

In terms of details you need to send to paypal, that will all be handled by Store in the checkout process. If will pass on the fields included in exp:store:checkout so it's all done for you in that respect.

I think Paypal Express *does* require the user to have a Paypal account but I think [there is a way around it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7689640/paypal-express-checkout-pay-without-account).

Comment: Users do not need to have a PayPal account to checkout if you choose PayPal Account Optional setting from the PayPal Account Required option in the CP. Also you can choose which Tab on PayPal the user will see (Guest Checkout/Create Account or Login Page). Full Documentation is avilable https://exp-resso.com/docs/store/payment_gateways.html#paypal-express-checkout

The only thing required by PayPal to be passed is the order_email (which is actually required for all of the gateways)